# Libgdx: how to implement a dialog?

Tags: java, android, 2d, libgdx

good day sirs. I've been struggling with this dialog because it keeps on saying I should have a table skin for my table but I'm not even using a table. However I have a skin ".atlas" file which contains packed images for my graphical user interface such as windows buttons.

Is there any way I could resolve this problem?aside from ".json" is there anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My modal dialog worked using another stage. When I wanted to show it, I changed the `InputProcessor` to my dialogs internal stage so other GUI objects couldn't respond to user input outside the dialog.

I found LIBGDX's dialogs overkill for my purposes. Perhaps you need a skin for your dialog?  If not I'd just go with my approach. You could always use a texture atlas instead. It can function much like a skin as strings are used to reference regions of an image.

Comment: I did create pack my images to atlases, but the problem is I still keep on getting errors which says I should use skin for my table. I never use any table though. You are right it is quite overkill. I will try your approach on my code. thanks :)